# PageBuilder error when saving category magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, page-builder

On category page when try to save category has error on console (**[ERROR] Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks.**) Can't save category changes.  I try these solutions but it doesn't work https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/issues/162, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25620. I have porto theme and module Smartwave_Maegamenu. Please help =)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found bug in Smartmage/Megamenu on **category_form.xml** and fix it. You need to apply changes for all fields(wyswig). Please take a look example for **sw_menu_block_top_content** field. Now it'll work with Magento Page Builder.

```
<field name="sw_menu_block_top_content" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="90" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Top menu</label>
                <dataScope>sw_menu_block_top_content</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

Comment: What was the problem??

Comment: I wrote in detail solution. The problem was in Smartmage_Megamenu module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using text editor in your block/dynamic block, check that text editor having any HTML tags. if yes just use HTML editor instead of text editor, this resolved a problem for me.